# algorithm that receives a number and a digit and checks how many times the digit is inside the number

Tags: c++, function

EDITed: works now

I have just started my first year at college, and we got some homework to do.

We were asked to create a function that receives a number and a digit from the user and print how many times the digit is in that number.
In addition, we are supposed to used const integers that are mentioned at the top of my algorithm- and return NEGATIVE_INPUT_NUMBER in case the number is negative or ILLEGAL_DIGIT in case the digit is negative or more than 9.
I wonder what is wrong with my program?It doesn't work for some reason.Can someone explain me why?

Thanks a lot

There it is:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    const int NEGATIVE_INPUT_NUMBER = -1;
    const int ILLEGAL_DIGIT = -2;
    int digitInNumber(int number, int digit);

    void main()
    {
        int digit,number;
        cout<< "Please insert a number and then a digit" << endl;
        cin>> number >>digit;
        cout << digitInNumber(number, digit) << endl;
    }
    int digitInNumber(int number,int digit)
    {
        int lastDig;
        int counter = 0;
        if (number < 0)
            return NEGATIVE_INPUT_NUMBER;
        if (digit > 9 || digit < 0)
            return ILLEGAL_DIGIT;
        while (number>0)
        {
            lastDig = number % 10;
            if (lastDig == digit)
                counter++;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        return counter;
```

Comment: This isn't the problem, but main should return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: _"It doesn't work"_ is not a problem description. Why not? What error do you get? Also, you seem to have missed some of your code while pasting; you should [edit] it to make sure it's all there. And it's not considered good style to use `ALL_CAPS` for anything except macros, which you should avoid anyway.

Comment: Thanks.I got some errors I didnt know what they meant so I just wrote that it doesnt work..well next time I will mention them. I edited the code, it works now.. but only one is missing for me now. I want it to return an error right after I insert for example -150 instead of waiting for the second input(digit).. how do i do that

Comment: If you have a new question, post a new question, or at least update this one so it reflects what you're asking. Comments are not for essential information.

Answer (score 1):

In function `digitInNumber`, you register the result of the modulo operation in number while you should save it in an other variable:

```
int digitInNumber(int number,int digit)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int lastDigit = 0;
    if (number < 0)
        return NEGATIVE_INPUT_NUMBER;
    if (digit > 9 || digit < 1)
        return ILLEGAL_DIGIT;
    while (number>0)
    {
        lastDigit = number % 10;
        if (lastDigit == digit)
            counter++;
        number = number / 10;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Your version was "forgetting" the value of number after the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thank you! I changed it now. I still got an error for "type int unexpected"

Comment: Well, that might be because you' would have to declare lastDigit at the beginning of the function. I changed my post accordingly

Comment: @Corali That's because you have `int digit, int number;` in `main`. The second `int` shouldn't be there.

Comment: Aha! thats right. I changed it and no errors now.  Only one thing: When I type for example -150(for number) it is waiting for the digit as well.How can I "break" it?I mean, right after it gets a wrong input it should return an error

Comment: You are using the logic of @Corali 's code there, but why a 0 should be an illegal digit?

Comment: @Corali if you want to stop the program after the `number`input, you can seperate your line `cin >> number >> digit` into two lines `cin >> number; cin >> digit;` and put a check on number in between them

Answer (score 1):

This statement is wrong:

```
number = number % 10;
```

It changes the value of `number` to something you don't want. Introduce a temporary local variable `tempint` and use it instead:

```
tempint = number % 10;
if (tempint == digit) {
    counter++;
}
```

or simply remove that statement and modify the `if` condition to:

```
if (number % 10 == digit) {
    counter++;
}
```

Alternative is to convert the integer number to string and integer digit to char and utilize the [std::count](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) function:

```
int digitInNumber(int no, int dig) {
    std::cout << "Enter number and a digit: ";
    std::cin >> no >> dig;
    std::string number = std::to_string(no);
    char digit = dig + '0';
    int num_items1 = std::count(number.begin(), number.end(), digit);
    return num_items1;
}
```

Comment: Because it is a year-1 college exercise, I suppose that thy're are not allowed to use the standard library (except cin and cout)

Comment: @Ron in principle I agree, however, not always when c++ is used for teaching the topic is c++. In any case OP wont learn by copy pasting your solution and you dont answer the question (what is wrong with OPs code?)

Answer (score 0):

For starters according to the C++ Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main()
```

> ILLEGAL_DIGIT in case the digit is negative or more than 9

The condition in this if statement does not satisfies the requirement.

```
    if (digit > 9 || digit < 1)
        return ILLEGAL_DIGIT;
```

Consider for example such a call like

```
digitInNumber( 1010, 0 );
```

Each variable should be declared in the scope where it is used. The variable

```
int lastDig;
```

is not used in the outer scope of the function `digitInNumber`.

Do not use magic numbers as 10. Use named constants.

The function can look the following way.

```
int digitInNumber(int number, int digit)
{
    const int Base = 10;

    if (number < 0)
    {
        return NEGATIVE_INPUT_NUMBER;
    }

    if (digit >= Base || digit < 0)
    {
        return ILLEGAL_DIGIT;
    }

    int counter = 0;

    do
    {
        counter += number % Base == digit;
    } while (number /= Base);

    return counter;
}
```

Or more general approach to write the function is to add one more parameter.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

const int NEGATIVE_INPUT_NUMBER = -1;
const int ILLEGAL_DIGIT = -2;

int digitInNumber(int number, int digit, int base = 10)
{
    const int DEFAULT_BASE = 10;
    const int MINIMUM_BASE = 2;
    const int MAXIMUM_BASE = 16;

    if (base < MINIMUM_BASE or base > MAXIMUM_BASE) base = DEFAULT_BASE;

    if (number < 0)
    {
        return NEGATIVE_INPUT_NUMBER;
    }

    if (digit >= base or digit < 0)
    {
        return ILLEGAL_DIGIT;
    }

    int counter = 0;

    do
    {
        counter += number % base == digit;
    } while (number /= base);

    return counter;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << digitInNumber(0, 0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << digitInNumber(10, 0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << digitInNumber(1010, 0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << digitInNumber(0xff, 0xf, 16) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1
1
2
2
```

Pay attention to this call

```
std::cout << digitInNumber(0xff, 0xf, 16) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, in plain c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

// returns the number of occurrences of 'c' in 's'
size_t count_occurrences(const std::string& s, char c)
{
    size_t n = 0;
    for (std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (*it == c)
            ++n;
    }
    return n;
}

bool validate_number(const std::string& s)
{
    return s.length() && s.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == std::string::npos;
}

bool validate_digit(const std::string& s)
{
    return s.length() == 1 && isdigit(s[0]);
}

int  main()
{
    std::string number, s;
    char digit = 0;

    for(;;)
    {
        std::cout<< "Please insert a number: ";
        std::cin >> number;

        if (validate_number(number))
            break;

        std::cout<< "Invalid entry! Please try again.\n";
    }

    for (;;)
    {
        std::cout<< "Please insert a digit to look for: ";
        std::cin >> s;

        if (validate_digit(s))
        {
            digit = s[0];
            break;
        }

        std::cout<< "Invalid entry! Please try again.\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Count: " << count_occurrences(number, digit) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```